# double and int problem in flutter using firebase values

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

hello iam new to flutter and iam facing this problem which i really don't know what to do about ,
i have this in my firestore :
[image]

when i was getting my price values as int it works just fine and i can make a cart item , but when i changed them to double it get me the error that : `double is not a subtype of int`
here is my :

**Product Model:**

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class ProductModel {
  static const ID = "id";
  static const NAME = "name";
  static const PICTURE = "picture";
  static const PRICE = "price";
  static const DESCRIPTION = "description";
  static const CATEGORY = "category";
  static const RECENT = "recent";
  static const QUANTITY = "quantity";
  static const BRAND = "brand";
  static const SALE = "sale";
  static const SIZES = "sizes";

  String _id;
  String _name;
  String _picture;
  String _description;
  String _category;
  String _brand;
  int _quantity;
  List _price;
  bool _sale;
  bool _recent;
  List _sizes;

  String get id => _id;

  String get name => _name;

  String get picture => _picture;

  String get brand => _brand;

  String get category => _category;

  String get description => _description;

  int get quantity => _quantity;

  List get price => _price;

  bool get featured => _recent;

  bool get sale => _sale;

  List get sizes => _sizes;

  ProductModel.fromSnapshot(DocumentSnapshot snapshot) {
    _id = snapshot.data()[ID];
    _brand = snapshot.data()[BRAND];
    _sale = snapshot.data()[SALE];
    _description = snapshot.data()[DESCRIPTION] ?? " ";
    _recent = snapshot.data()[RECENT];
    _price = snapshot.data()[PRICE];
    _category = snapshot.data()[CATEGORY];
    _sizes = snapshot.data()[SIZES];
    _name = snapshot.data()[NAME];
    _picture = snapshot.data()[PICTURE];

  }
}
```

**CartModel:**

```
class CartItemModel {
  static const ID = "id";
  static const NAME = "name";
  static const IMAGE = "image";
  static const PRODUCT_ID = "productId";
  static const PRICE = "price";
  static const SIZE = "size";
  static const QUANTITY = "quantity";

  String _id;
  String _name;
  String _image;
  String _productId;
  String _size;
  int _price;
  int _quantity;

  //  getters
  String get id => _id;

  String get name => _name;

  String get image => _image;

  String get productId => _productId;

  String get size => _size;

  int get price => _price;
  int get quantity => _quantity;



  CartItemModel.fromMap(Map data){
    _id = data[ID];
    _name =  data[NAME];
    _image =  data[IMAGE];
    _productId = data[PRODUCT_ID];
    _price = data[PRICE];
    _size = data[SIZE];
    _quantity = data[QUANTITY];
  }

  Map toMap() => {
    ID: _id,
    IMAGE: _image,
    NAME: _name,
    PRODUCT_ID: _productId,
    PRICE: _price,
    SIZE: _size,
    QUANTITY:_quantity,
  };
}
```

**how i add to cart**

```
  Future<bool> addToCart(
      {ProductModel product, String size, int index,int quantity}) async {
    try {
      var uuid = Uuid();
      String cartItemId = uuid.v4();
      List<CartItemModel> cart = _userModel.cart;

      Map cartItem = {
        "quantity":1,
        "id": cartItemId,
        "name": product.name,
        "image": product.picture,
        "productId": product.id,
        "price": product.price[index],
        "size": size,
      };
```

Comment: your code seems fine to me, can you give more details about where you got the error? You also can check console for more info about the error and what causing it

Comment: can you connect with anydesk ? to see why ? this is making me go crazyyy

Comment: Surely you just need to change the type of price to double in the CartItemModel so that it maps correctly from the firebase double type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Dart Programing Language, you can use *integer literals* to assign a value to a double variable:

```dart
double x = 1;
```

It will properly infer that you meant `1.0`.

*Note: This is tolerated only since Dart 2.1*

**However**, Dart still is a Strongly Typed Programming Language. You cannot assign the value of an int variable to your double variable:

```dart
double x;
var y = 1; // Dart infer the type  y based on the value, hence an `int`.
x = y; // FAILS with "A value of type 'int' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'double'."
```

In your case, when you do `_price = data[PRICE]`, the type of `data[PRICE]` will be inferred at runtime as `int` or `double` for, as an example, `10` or `9.99`.

A solution would be to explicitly cast the value as `_price = data[PRICE].toDouble();`

---

[More info](https://dart.dev/tools/diagnostic-messages#invalid_assignment) about the Invalid Assignment error.

Comment: i know that i should use `toDouble()` but if i want to use it i should ues it with my `List price` not my `CartItemModel`  , to be converted to a double so my `CartItemModel` can accept it as a double and i can't use `toDouble` with a list

Comment: Nice Answer Bro

Answer (score 0):

Change the variable type from `int` to `double`

```
class CartItemModel {
      static const ID = "id";
      static const NAME = "name";
      static const IMAGE = "image";
      static const PRODUCT_ID = "productId";
      static const PRICE = "price";
      static const SIZE = "size";
      static const QUANTITY = "quantity";
    
      String _id;
      String _name;
      String _image;
      String _productId;
      String _size;
      double _price;
      int _quantity;
    
      //  getters
      String get id => _id;
    
      String get name => _name;
    
      String get image => _image;
    
      String get productId => _productId;
    
      String get size => _size;
    
      double get price => _price;
      int get quantity => _quantity;
    
    
    
      CartItemModel.fromMap(Map data){
        _id = data[ID];
        _name =  data[NAME];
        _image =  data[IMAGE];
        _productId = data[PRODUCT_ID];
        _price = data[PRICE];
        _size = data[SIZE];
        _quantity = data[QUANTITY];
      }
    
      Map toMap() => {
        ID: _id,
        IMAGE: _image,
        NAME: _name,
        PRODUCT_ID: _productId,
        PRICE: _price,
        SIZE: _size,
        QUANTITY:_quantity,
      };
    }
```

Comment: can i ask , if the price is int and that is smth that can be the app doesnot recognize it all

Comment: It depends on how you develop the app. I just tried to find what was wrong in your code